# browser no longer displaying gradient background

Tags: css, background, gradient

I'm trying to put a banner image (with transparent section) in a div, over a gradient background that I can change dynamically, and then overlay a table on top of it all.

```
    <div style="margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 796px; position: relative; ">
        <img src="LeftSlice.gif" style="margin: 0; padding: 0; position: relative; float: left;">
        <div style="margin: 0; padding: 0; 
            background: -webkit-linear-gradient(white, blue);
            background: -o-linear-gradient(white, blue);
            background: -moz-linear-gradient(white, blue);
            background: linear-gradient(white, blue);
            ">
            <img src="MiddleSlice2.gif"  style="margin: 0; padding: 0; position: relative; float: left;  z-index: 250; ">
        </div>
        <img src="RightSlice.gif" style="margin: 0; padding: 0; position: relative; float: left; ">

        <table style="padding: 0 20px; width: 796px; position: absolute; left:10px; top:10px; z-index: 500 " >
        <tr>
            <td valign="bottom" align="left"><img src="IFFUlogo.gif" height="80px" width="200px" ></td>
            <td valign="top" align="right">About Us | Register | Login</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" valign="bottom" align="center" style="padding: 30px 0 0 0; color: white; "><h1>Custer County District High School</h1></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

I'm getting no gradient (body bg is showing under transparent portion of the banner .gif)

When I look at the element in Firebug, I get this:

```
element.style {
background: linear-gradient(#FFFFFF, #0000FF) repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
```

I don't think we are allowed to post URLs, but if so, I can do so.

Comment: You can post a URL, but a jsfiddle is a much better idea - the URL becomes useless once you fix your issue. A fiddle isolates the problem and is easier for everyone else to look at. Take your HTML and CSS, make a fiddle, share the link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like everything inside your divs is either floating or `position:absolute`. This will cause the divs to collapse in on themselves, so that you can't see the background. Anytime you float something inside of a container that you want to expand to contain its contents, you either need to insert a `clear` like this:

```
<div id="myContainer" style="background:red;">
  <img id="myFloatingElem" style="float:left;" />
  <div style="clear:left;"></div>
</div>
```

Or better yet, don't do that, and use a [Clearfix](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/) instead (See http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/ for accompanying css):

```
<div id="myContainer" class="cf" style="background:red;">
  <img id="myFloatingElem" style="float:left;" />
</div>
```

For `position:absolute`, neither option will work, you need to specify a height for the parent in this case.

Comment: when I add the <div style="clear:left;"></div> after the img, the gradient bg works great, but the other two images ("LeftSlice.gif" and "RightSlice.gif") are thrown down below the div on top of each other.

Here's a fiddle: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/Zu8wJ/2/)

Comment: I'm sure I'm approaching this all wrong, being inept at css. Would welcome fixes to overall approach, as well.

Comment: I tried to make this work with as few tweaks as possible -- Use a clearfix like this: http://jsfiddle.net/Zu8wJ/3/

Comment: To take this further, I would recommend ditching the absolutely positioned table and actually put the content inside the header div itself. Just make those 3 floated images into a single background image instead, which seems like what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I stumbled on the "combine the three images into one" solution as well, and it's working. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I tested your CSS gradient code and it works. I see the problem is in the `float: left` of the image inside the `div` tag with the gradient background but I don't know what output you wish to see because the image files are not available. Maybe you can post it clearly.

Comment: Thanks! I added a fiddle in another comment, if you have time to look at what I'm trying to do.